# PHP, MySQL prepared statements - can you use results of execute more than once by calling data_seek(0)?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a case where I want to use the results of a prepared statement more than once in a nested loop. The outer loop processes the results of another query, and the inner loop is the results of the prepared statement query. So the code would be something like this (just "pseudoish" to demonstrate the concept):

```
// not showing the outer query, it is just a basic SELECT, not prepared statement
// we'll call it $outer_query

$obj_array = array();   // going to save objects in this
$ids = array(18,19,20); // just example id numbers

$query = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($var1, $var2);
    $stmt->store_result(); // I think I need this for data_seek

    while ($q1 = $outer_query->fetch_object()) {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if ($q1->field1 == $var1) { // looking for a match
               $obj = new stdClass();
               $obj->var1 = $var1;
               $obj->var2 = $var2;

               $obj_array[] = $obj;
               $stmt->data_seek(0); // reset for outer loop
               break;               // found match, so leave inner                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I seem to be experiencing is that the values are not getting bound in the variables as I would expect after the first time I use fetch in the inner loop. Specifically, in one example I ran with 3 ids for the foreach, the first id was processed correctly, the second was processed incorrectly (matches were not found in the inner loop even though they existed), and then the third was processed correctly.

Is there something wrong with the prepared statment function calls in the sequence I am doing above, or is this an invalid way to use the results of the prepared statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where this code was going wrong. It had nothing to do with my use of the prepared statement functions, just the placement of the data_seek. I sought help from SO a little too soon :)

The loop code that now works exactly as I wanted is as follows:

```
while ($q1 = $outer_query->fetch_object()) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($q1->field1 == $var1) { // looking for a match
            $obj = new stdClass();
            $obj->var1 = $var1;
            $obj->var2 = $var2;
            $obj_array[] = $obj;
            break;               // found match, so leave inner                
        }
    }
    $stmt->data_seek(0); // reset for outer loop
}
// this was always here, forgot it in original post
$outer_query->data_seek(0) // reset for next iteration of foreach
```

When I was calling data_seek inside the conditional to reset the prepared statment results, the reset was occurring only if a match was found. This caused the outer loop to run in specific situations with the prepared statement result not reset. Sometimes the forest is hidden by the trees ;)

So, apparently you can easily process prepared statement results multiple times using data_seek, just as I had hoped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use JOIN to make it with single query and no loops

And you don't need any data_seek anyway.

Comment: The actual situation is more complex than what I have shown above, and a JOIN to make a single query would not work. What I wanted to know above is if there was anything wrong with the concept of using a prepared statement as shown above in the loop, and any obvious reason why I would not be able to reset and fetch() on the same results multiple times. Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I am sorry @Carvell but that's impossible. No JOIN can make a query  not working. You're just going wrong way because of lack of experience. You'd better learn proper way instead of sticking with wrong one. It's a life. Sometimes answers we've got are not ones we have asked.

Comment: I think you and I are having a failure to communicate :) I did find the problem I was having (see below). I reexamined to see if there was a way to get the results I need in a single query, but in this case, I just don't think that will work. I didn't want to go into all the complexity of my actual situation because it would make the question too lengthy, so you had the disadvantage of not having all the details. Sorry about that. Thanks again for your input. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Carvell Don't hesitate to make question detailed and specific. It always helps, despite of length.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the mysql result to an array, and then you can use array functions to navigate through the array. Data_seek isn't very elegant, IMO.

Comment: that's too far from the actual question again :)

Comment: why go through the extra work to convert the result to an array? Also, what is your rationale for saying that data_seek isn't elegant? Isn't it designed to do exactly what I am using it for? Reset the pointer back to the beginning (or any specific location) in a result set?